# driving along and then stalling..... and never to start again..... what is it?

Tags: hyundai, stall, power, towing, suv

I brought a second hand Hyundai IX35 2015 model, which has less than 100k kms. I was driving home and felt it jerk forward, the motor sounded strange (at this stage I'd only had the vehicle 6 weeks), I had to slow down for an intersection and I lost all power the car stalled itself at the intersection, the radio/ lights on the dash all worked and lit up the dash. The car started once after stalling, but didn't have the rev's to stay idling. I tried to jumpstart the car but that didn't help in anyway. Just wondering what the problem could be, and how long it could take to fix. The car has now been towed and is currently sitting at the workshop waiting on repairs... Just wondering what the duration/ cost could be along with the diagnosis could be.

Comment: Your title: " never to start again" - is that true - it *never* started again? Or is it just idling poorly?  Does it crank when you turn the key?

Comment: The car will crank but it doesn't fire. There is power- the radio does work. but not enough life to start the vehicle

Comment: What do mean not enough life? Does it crank only slowly?

Comment: It sounds like the engine stopped getting fuel. Could be lots of things: clogged fuel filter, clogged injectors, bad fuel pump. Should be quick to fix. Cost is dependent on what went wrong.

Comment: My guess is the timing belt/chain.  Though the started once after stalling sounds odd.